# Default screen as login Screen

Tags: php, yii2, rbac

In Yii2 - I have successfully setup authentication module with user setup with database. I can prevent access to specific controller using access control.

I have taken the following steps, which works partially:
Created a separate layout in `views\layouts\authorization.php`

```
`virtually a Blank-Layout`
```

And then added the layout in my `site controller` in `login action` I have added

```
$this->layout = 'authorization';
```

Which is working fine.

Now how can I make the site/login as the default controller?

I am able to change the **default controller** in config like:

```
'defaultRoute' => 'site/login',
```

But then I am getting the **error after login** like:

```
The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
```

So I need to resolve just one issue.

Redirecting to home-page after login. As my method of setting default controller don't work correctly after login.

**Note: if I am not setting the default route in config, the redirect is working fine.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the solution, actually instead of `defaultRoute' => 'site/login'`, you can provide any other controller, which needs authentication.

for example

```
defaultRoute' => 'site/index'
```

and it will not have the circular problem of redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [here](https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin). It provides all the functionality that you have mentioned.